# Set a column to updatable=false in hibernate generated via reverse engineering

Tags: hibernate, reverse-engineering

I am trying to generate an entity via reverse engineering and there is a `@JoinColumn` field via `@ManyToOne` relationship that I want to mark as `updatable="false"` as due to MVP concept we don't want to update this field during CRUD operation.

I have tried below configuration in my hibernate.reveng.xml file to override the entity definition:

```
 <table schema="sch" name="ChildTable">
    <column name="fk1" property="fk1">
      <meta attribute="updatable">false</meta>
    </column>
  </table>
```

Below is my generated field as of now:

```
 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name = "fk1")
 private ParentTable parentTable;
```

Field to be generated via reverse engineering:

```
 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name = "fk1",updateable="false")
 private ParentTable parentTable;
```

Can somebody please suggest what can be done here?